# How to disable auto scroll on dropdown of mat-select in angular material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dropdown

Scenario:
I type in letters in keyboard and the mat-select dropdown automatically scrolls(jumps) to the element in dropdown list.
For eg. if I type 'I' it is scrolling to Inventory while I want to search for the word 'Id'.
my list is not sorted.. 
so i want to avoid autoscroll to the word starting with letter
Can anyone help?

Comment: my list is not sorted.. so i want to avoid autoscroll to the word starting with letter

Comment: can you please provide code which you have tried ?

Comment: Have you found any solution? setting "typeaheadDebounceInterval" is a workaround but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: i ended up using an npm package and dropped the plan to implement it by myself

Answer (score 0):

You can set typeaheadDebounceInterval on mat-select to e.g. 500 ms to delay the jump. Then you could have written 2 characters, e.g. i then d, so it will jump to the right word.

Disabling the jump is not possible. It is built-in in native html  elements